# How to slice string till particular character in Go?

Tags: string, go, substring, slice

I want to extract a string till a character is found. For example:

```
message := "Rob: Hello everyone!"
user := strings.Trim(message,
```

I want to be able to store `"Rob"` (read till `':'` is found).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may use [`strings.IndexByte()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#IndexByte) or [`strings.IndexRune()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#IndexRune) to get the position (byte-index) of the colon `':'`, then simply [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) the `string` value:

```
message := "Rob: Hello everyone!"
user := message[:strings.IndexByte(message, ':')]
fmt.Println(user)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4znXPNn_0d)):

```
Rob
```

If you're not sure the colon is in the `string`, you have to check the index before proceeding to slice the `string`, else you get a runtime panic. This is how you can do it:

```
message := "Rob: Hello everyone!"
if idx := strings.IndexByte(message, ':'); idx >= 0 {
    user := message[:idx]
    fmt.Println(user)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Invalid string")
}
```

Output is the same.

Changing the message to be invalid:

```
message := "Rob Hello everyone!"
```

Output this time is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NVY4nrQMu7)):

```
Invalid string
```

Another handy solution is to use [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split):

```
message := "Rob: Hello everyone!"

parts := strings.Split(message, ":")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", parts)

if len(parts) > 1 {
    fmt.Println("User:", parts[0])
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7CpQa0Hisb)):

```
["Rob" " Hello everyone!"]
User: Rob
```

Should there be no colon in the input `string`, `strings.Split()` returns a slice of strings containing a single `string` value being the input (the code above does not print anything in that case as length will be `1`).

Answer (score 6):

[strings.Index](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index) or [strings.IndexRune](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#IndexRune), depending on whether you want to use unicode as the separator, will give you the index of the sought character.

Alternatively, you can use strings.Split and just grab the first string returned.

Example: `user := strings.Split(message, ":")[0]`

https://play.golang.org/p/I1P1Liz1F6

Notably, this will not panic if the separator character is not in the original string, but the `user` variable will be set to the entirety of the original string instead.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers don't mention this, but Go 1.18 saw the addition of a [very convenient](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46336) [`strings.Cut` function](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Cut), which obviates the need to deal with indices:

```golang
message := "Rob: Hello everyone!"
before, after, found := strings.Cut(message, ":")
fmt.Printf("%q %q %t\n", before, after, found) // "Rob" " Hello everyone!" true

message = "Rob Hello everyone!"
before, after, found = strings.Cut(message, ":")
fmt.Printf("%q %q %t\n", before, after, found) // "Rob Hello everyone!" "" false
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/YwEnLjZIJhS))